# What is the Bash Escape Character "\c"?

Tags: bash, unix, escaping, echo

What is the name and function of the `\c` escape character in Bash? What is its numeric value? I have seen that `\cx` is a control character, but what about plain `\c`? It seems that:

```
echo -e "Hello World\c"
```

and

```
echo -en "Hello World"
```

are equivalent. However, Python doesn't use it as an escape character, and it is missing from all of the lists of escape characters I found. Is this a Bash-specific behavior?

Comment: i tried that in c and it prints "c" on the screen http://codepad.org/sBWJfPkc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's actually specific to some versions of `echo` (I'm pretty sure that `\c` came from SysV while the `-n` version was a BSD-ism).

It simply means don't output the trailing newline.

Answer (score 12):

See the [echo man page](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html) or the section on echo in the [Bash Builtins section of the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins):

> echo interprets the following escape sequences:
>
> ...
>   \c
>        suppress further output

Comment: Thanks for the references and the confirmation of paxdiablo's answer.

Comment: worth mentioning that \c is not recognized ,if -e is not in effect.

Answer (score 4):

It's the 'End of Text' control character; it informs the Shell that the end of text has been reached.

Not entirely sure that it's relevant any more, but I could be wrong.

here's the doc:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters

and:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character

Comment: CTRL-C is the ETX character but that has very little to do with this particular case, otherwise FF would be \l instead of \f, newline woulf be \j rather than \n and so forth.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, \c is ETX, that's what I said - what is FF ?

Comment: Hi @Russ C, I appreciate the answer.
However, it does seem that @paxdiablo is right. For example, try: `echo -e "Hello World\03"` (the link you gave listed the numerical value of ETX as 3). It does not give the same result as `echo -e "Hello World\c"`.

Comment: No problem; glad you have a solution! I wasn't considering that \c might be interpreted as hex 12, just that it was a control character.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your question with a little more context on how the \c is being used?

You can use `\c` to escape control characters that you may, say write to a file, or pipe as input to another command.

This will write to the terminal the text "some command" followed by binary ctrl-d (ascii 0x4):

```
echo some control string $'\cd'
```

See full list of escape characters from the bash man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Answer (score -1):

"\c" means produce no further output.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.