# Using read without triggering a newline action on terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, newline

I currently have this

```bsh
$PROMPT=">"
while read -p "${PROMPT}" line; do
  echo -en "\r"
  some_info_printout($line)
  echo -en "\n${PROMPT}"
done
```

which gives output like this

```
>typed input
INFO OUT ["typed input"]
>more text
INFO OUT ["more text"]
>
```

what I would like is to do a `read` and ignore the newline action such that preciding text can overwrite the existing line

```
INFO OUT ["typed input"]
INFO OUT ["more text"]
>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `-s` would be over the top since the program would be difficult to type correctly into

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> that causes `read` to return necessarily moves the cursor to the next line. You need to use terminal escapes to get it back to the previous line.
 And the rest of your script has some problems anyway. Here's something that works, it should give you a better starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

PROMPT=">"
while read -p "${PROMPT}" line; do
        echo -en "\033[1A\033[2K"
        echo "You typed: $line"
done
```

`\033` is an <kbd>Esc</kbd>; the `\033[1A` moves the cursor to the previous line, `\033[2K` erases whatever was on it.

Comment: FWIW, bash's echo also recognizes the escape sequence `\e` for escapes.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to keep the cursor on the same line after `echo` could be to use `\c` escape character along with `-e` flag.

```
echo -e "Want to do something fun? (y/n) \c"
read -r
echo "You answered: $REPLY"
```

**Note:** It might be specific to some versions of `echo`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154820/2110909