# How to echo some content and read user input and then echo some content on the same line?

Tags: bash

```
echo -e -n "Enter the search string: "; read string1; echo " $string1 was found $count times in our database";

Output:
Enter the search string: xyz

xyz was found 10 times in our database
```

But i need the output as below

```
Enter the search string: xyz  xyz was found 10 times in our database
```

how to get this way?

Comment: should there be any escape sequence to let the interpreter know read is a command

Comment: I think the answer here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134638/using-read-without-triggering-a-newline-action-on-terminal