# sed is not working with certain string characters

Tags: sed

I have been reading through the various sed issues and have one I cannot get to work:

I want to replace:

```
define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', CIVICRM_DSN);
```

With

```
define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', myuser:mypassword@localhost:3306\civicrm_uat_logs);
```

This *almost* works...

```
sed -i -e "s/define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', CIVICRM_DSN);/define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', 'myuser:mypassword@localhost:3306\civicrm_uat_logs');/" /my_path/civicrm.settings.php
```

The output is:

```
define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', myuser:mypassword@localhost:3306  vicrm_uat_logs);
```

The issue is I get is that missing 'ci'. This, I assume is due to the backslash, but why two chars?!  If I had 'my_database' instead of civicrm_uat_logs , I'd just lose the backslash.

I cannot seem to escape the backslash no matter, but maybe something else is going on?

Struggling with this one, but it must be simple...

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

UPDATE:

I realsed that I needed quotes around the database string... so the replacement should be:

```
define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', 'myuser:mypassword@localhost:3306\civicrm_uat_logs');
```

Now,nothing get's replaced but no error...

Comment: Double the backslash in the replacement.

Comment: `\c` [seems to suppress output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154800/what-is-the-bash-escape-character-c) of the following symbols.

Comment: \c does something weird and when I add the quotes in, I get no replacement at all.  I cannot seem to escape the \c...

Comment: See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) as it covers this case and others you might run into if you want to use sed for this (instead of awk or some other tool that understands literal strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with the help of a kind and knowledgeable friend.  The shell and sed are nested so:

```
sed -i -e "s/define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', CIVICRM_DSN);/define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', 'civicrm:civicrm@db:3306\\\\civicrm_uat_logs');/"
```

Escaping both the backslash and the '\c'

Answer (score -1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E "s/([^,]*, ).*/\1myuser:mypassword@localhost:3306\\\civicrm_uat_logs);/" input_file
define('CIVICRM_LOGGING_DSN', myuser:mypassword@localhost:3306\civicrm_uat_logs);
```